# Not able to run any command i.e mkmetric even though openTSDB service is up and running in port 4242

Tags: opentsdb

While executing below command I am getting the below error

```
./tsdb mkmetric mymetric

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
at net.opentsdb.tools.CliOptions.honorVerboseFlag(CliOptions.java:161)
at net.opentsdb.tools.CliOptions.parse(CliOptions.java:82)
at net.opentsdb.tools.UidManager.main(UidManager.java:97)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can try by adding --verbose argument.

```
./tsdb mkmetric mymetric --verbose=class
```